# AS3 Preloader Cache Problem?

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader

So the following code is Lee's implementation of a preloader which works fine first load but goes crazy when the browser loads a cached file, jumping from 0% to 100% randomly

Things I have tried to no avail:

- switching off gzip compression, tho I dont think it is on
- Using ENTER_FRAME instead of progress
  and complete

  ```
      l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
      l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
      l.load(new URLRequest("http://www.foo.com/foo.swf"));

      function loop(e:ProgressEvent):void
      {
          perc = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100);
          lt.text = String(perc);
          if (perc >= 100)
              l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
      }

      function done(e:Event):void
      {
          l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
          addChild(l);
      }
  ```

I do not believe I am loading it more than once:

```
public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);  
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            Security.allowDomain("http://www.foo.com");
            preLoader();
        }
```

Comment: are you loading the same file over and over?

Comment: I updated the post to hopefully show its not loading over and over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem happens because the files are hosted on an addon domain.

To fix this I changed the url to reference the main domain:

from

```
l.load(new URLRequest("http://www.foo.com/foo.swf"))
```

to

```
l.load(new URLRequest("http://foo.maindomain.com/foo.swf"))
```

and also add

```
Security.allowDomain("http://foo.maindomain.com");
```